# How to ignore one string in wiredep paths

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, wiredep

I have three gulp tasks:

First task - compiles all jade files to html, inject all my css and js with wiredep plugin from bower.json

```
/* Compile jade templates to html files in app directory */
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src(config.path.dev.jade + '/index.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: '\t'
    }))
    .pipe(wiredep({
        ignorePath: '../'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'))
    .pipe(notify(config.message.jadeCompiled))
});
```

Result after task:

```
<!-- bower:js-->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/nodernizr-dev/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<!-- endbower-->
```

Second task - take lastest version jQuery from bower.json and change URL with gulp-google-cdn plugin

```
/* Change JQuery from bower directory to Google CDN URL */
gulp.task('cdn', function () {
     return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe(googlecdn(require('./bower.json')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
        .pipe(notify(config.message.cdnComplete))
});
```

Result after task:

```
<!-- bower:js-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/nodernizr-dev/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<!-- endbower-->
```

Third task - use wiredep plugin again to change my paths to production

```
/* Normalize paths to production */
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    return gulp.src('./dist/index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
        ignorePath: '../src/bower_components/',
        exclude: 'jquery',
        fileTypes: {
            html: {
                replace: {
                    js: '<script src="js/vendor/{{filePath}}"></script>',
                    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/{{filePath}}" />'
                }
            }
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

I have this result

```
<!-- bower:js-->
<script src="js/vendor/nodernizr-dev/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<!-- endbower-->
```

But I want just ignore one string (where my Google CDN URL) like that

```
<!-- bower:js-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/nodernizr-dev/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<!-- endbower-->
```

Comment: where to ignore,what to ignore, not getting

Comment: _Where?_ In index.html, section <!-- bower:js-->...<!-- endbower-->, in all result-blocks I showed this section. _What?_ Ignore one string with Google CDN JQuery URL, I showed what I want and what I receive (after third task)